# Can't get while loop to work, input twice?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class InputLoop
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter an integer to continue or a non-integer to finish");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input = scan.nextInt();
        while(scan.hasNextInt())
        {
            System.out.println("Enter an integer to continue or a non-integer to finish");
            scan.next();
        }


    }
}
```

This is the first while loop i've written, and when it runs, I have to input a number twice before it proceeds to print "Enter an integer to continue....." 
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be much better as a do ...while loop. Essentially, it is the same, except you check the condition after you are done.

```
    do
    {
        System.out.println("Enter an integer to continue or a non-integer to finish");
        scan.next();
    } while(scan.hasNextInt());
```

Although if you did it as a while, you could add in a dummy variable to make sure you go through at least once.

```
Boolean firstTime=true;
while(firstTime==true || scan.hasNextInt())
    {
        firstTime=true;
        System.out.println("Enter an integer to continue or a non-integer to finish");
        scan.next();
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

according to docs - [`Scanner#hasNextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29)

> Returns true if the next token in this scanner's input can be interpreted as an
>   int value in the default radix using the nextInt() method. The scanner does not
>   advance past any input.